# How to retrieve data from PC's Hyperterminal

Tags: windows-xp

We will be building a facility by which we can send some information to the PC from external Hardware device ie. Microcontroller .The information will be displayed on the "Hyper Terminal" of the PC .We can interface a microcontroller to the PC and the output could be possibly displayed on the PC's Hyperterminal .Our requirement is , we need to extract the data from "Hyperterminal" show this on a website. So, is there any way by which we can we can get the data from the Hyperterminal and put it to the website. My guess is , we have to do some coding  through which we can collect data from "Hyperterminal" destop application and need to put it on web application . We are  unclear about the programming language selection that would preferably suite and serve the best in this situation . We are developers in  PHP , Flex and C but we are in dilemma , that is it required to create a destop application using .net / java , or there is a API interface of the hyperterminal which can be used .

I will be very grateful and it will be a great help to us , if you suggest which programming techniques that can be used to achieve the aforesaid objective . I request you to put some light on the methodologies , technologies involved that we need to take into consideration .

Comment: Unless you use some funny protocol, just interact directly with the serial port.

Comment: IIRC hyperterminal will capture data to a file; however this would be inconvenient for routine use compared to having a custom application which opens the serial port as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What about intermediate "proxy" application, that connects to microcontroller (via RS232 or how you do it) and creates socket that may be used for hyperterminal connection. This application must act as a simple bridge and transmit data from MC connection to socket and vice versa. Also this application can collect all necessary data and write it to database. Web application reads data from DB.

Comment: Actually we can display the information from Microcontroller in the Hyperterminal. Now the problem is we don't know how to extract that data from Hyperterminal everytime we get some new data. We need to put it into the database. We are using Embedded C for our programming. We are confused to choose which language to get data from Hyperterminal and to put it on database. I think we can use java or .Net for this. But we are not sure. Please help us.

Comment: Why do you use Hyperterminal? Is it really necessary? When I worked with MC I used Hyperterminal only for debugging MC program, later I implemented simple protocol and wrote program (in С++) that controlled device and received data.