# storing array values(from microcontroller) shown on hyperterminal to an excel sheet in PC

Tags: c, windows-7, embedded

I want to save the array values(from microcontroller) shown on  hyperterminal  to an excel sheet in PC and the same question posted here but has no conlcusions

[How to retrieve data from PC's Hyperterminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922608/how-to-retrieve-data-from-pcs-hyperterminal)

Can anyone please guide me about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm curious if after all this, you'll be implementing the uC program in VBA.

Comment: Look, it's like this.  First, HyperTerminal is just about the worst terminal app on the planet.  The only people who use it are engineers out in the field who suddenly realise that they need a serial terminal and HT is all they have on their laptop.
Use VC++ or C# to read data from the uC. Shove it into Excel using COM automation.  Delete Hyperterminal from your system.

Comment: @MartinJames - and then you discover that Windows 7 no longer has hyperterminal.

Comment: ...and then you get hyperthermia.

Comment: Buy you definitely always have Putty on your usb stick. :)

Comment: I'm using HT for just viewing my output but I'm required  to write the output from uC to the excel sheet on PC automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to tell hyperterminal to log the session to a file.  It may help to use an extension of .csv or rename it later.

Open the file in a text editor and trim out any extraneous beginning/end data. You might have to run a find/replace or two to fix up delimiters

Open the .csv file in Excel and play with the field delimiter settings until you have your data in something approaching the needed columns.

A command line utility called sed can help you a lot with automating delimiter modifications; it's standard on unix-like operating systems, but available for windows (even in a stand alone form).  It has a learning curve, but it is very good at this type of thing.

Comment: Thnks fr your suggestion but I need save the data from uC automatically on a excel sheet in PC.

Comment: @user1016528 then hyperterminal is probably not part of your solution.  Change your question to be something to the effect of 'Automatically capture and import serial port data to spreadsheet' though you will probably also want to state what programming languages you are comfortable working in.